# What are good resources to learn about web services for an iOS developer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, wsdl

I am a C# developer which I specialize in Win forms and web application. I work in financial field and most of my experience is connecting to Oracle/sql/sybase and get data and display on the screen.

Recently I taught myself how to develop iPhone / iPad applications.  It went very well.  Now I want to learn how to connect using web services to my own databases and get data or upload data.

So I need to learn Web services, SOAP, WSDL and whatever else that I need.  I don't have any experience in it but if someone can direct me to the right books I will buy them and read them. i want to start writing in my office and connect to my databases and be able to do a proof of concept.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Particularly because you're starting out, I would suggest looking at [RESTful services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer).  The API is essentially a URL using HTTP GET, PUT, POST, or DELETE.  The output can be XML, JSON, whatever you want.  Very simple to construct and test.  And because the API is so simple, you don't necessarily need to add another library to your project and increase the code size.

The second chapter of the book [iPhone Games Projects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430219688) talks about how to use a RESTful rankings system to record game scores to a server from an iPhone game.

Comment: is this a book?  Where do I find it?  I click on the url and it goes to wikipedia. Thanks

Comment: The link in the first paragraph goes to a wiki page describing REST services very generally.  There's a second link in the second paragraph that takes you to Amazon where you can see some info about the book "iPhone Games Projects".

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need books for that subject. Try using some API's to make your life easier, and check some code samples. For example:

For JSON, SBJSON is a standard: https://github.com/stig/json-framework/

For XML, have a look at this Apple example: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SeismicXML/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007323

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to retrieve info from a online database is to use PHP. You simply call a PHP file located on your server from your iPhone application. The PHP file takes in info you sent it via GET/POST methods (if required), retrieves info from your database, and echo's it in XML/JSON.